# Linux block access to router login page

Tags: router, login, block

I am running virtual machines with Gnome desktops on Debian Squeeze and Wheezy.  The virtual machines are on a different subnet than the host.  I would like to block the virtual machines from accessing the router/firewall login page via Firefox, but still have access to the Internet.

Is there some way to do this with ufw, iptables, host.deny or possibly on the router itself using an address range (I can use Blocksite and lock down the config, but would prefer some other approach)?  I've tried various things, but either my attempts fail or I block access to Internet from the VMs.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the router, But you could do it from the client side as well.

Answer (score 0):

there are numbers of ways to accomplish that, since you didn't really provide much of details it's hard to suggest, but the idea is `iptables` can do that easily *OR* some routers will allow you to limit that as well.

Comment: Thanks - don't mean to be vague:  what type of detail would help?  E.g., with iptables have tried iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24 ! -d  xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source $EXTIP on the host.  This didn't work.  On dd-wrt router, have tried blocking the VM guest range in access restrictions, again without effect.  Can you give me a sense of what detail would help? Thanks!

Comment: Was hoping to get a specific suggestion for Iptables...suggested syntax?